# Performing a get() like operation on a ResultSet in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, find, cakephp-3.0

```
$id = 1;    
$product = $this->Products->get($id);
$offers = $this->Products->Offers->find()->where(['Offers.product_id' => $id]);
```

`$offers` will contain two kind of rows. One with `type` **`a`** that points to another row in `$offers` of `type` **`b`** using another field `offer_id`.

This is why I need a `Model->get()` like method that so that I can locate an item using the primary key of the result set.

In short, I need to get a result from result set by passing id.
Like for example by doing:

```
$offers->getResultByPrimaryKey($offer_id)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't really get the "_why_"... why don't you use associations and containments?

Comment: @ndm, I use associations. That's why u see `$this->Products->Offers` in my code.

Comment: I was mainly referring to the the `Offers` self-relation, as this seems to be where you want to fetch data from!?